# Using regex extract all digit and word numbers

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract all string and digit numbers from  a text.

```
text = 'one tweo three 10 number'
numbers = "(^a(?=\s)|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten| \
          eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen| \
          eighteen|nineteen|twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty| \
          ninety|hundred|thousand)"

print re.search(numbers, text).group(0)
```

This gives me first words digit.

my expected result = ['one', 'two', 'three', '10']

How can I modify it so that all words and well digit numbers I Can get in list?

Comment: Use `re.findall` and add `|[0-9]+` branch to your pattern. See https://ideone.com/w9Q0QZ. Is `tweo` a typo?

Comment: Well, there are more issues here. You need to also use word boundaries I believe, since you are mostly interested in whole words.

Comment: Why would you get a match on `10`?

Comment: No idea why you accepted an answer that does not work correctly, and I explained why in the comments to that answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I accepted another answer. But it failed for my test - `Possible to reserve French Laundry on 25th Dec at 6pm for 4 of us?` That another regex gave answer that is why I accepted it

Comment: You should always provide as many details as possible inside the question, otherwise, you will end up with a solution that will fail elsewhere. I updated my answer by moving `\d+` to match match in any contexts, and now, only word numerals are required to be whole words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here:

- The pattern should be used with the VERBOSE flag (add `(?x)` at the start)
- The `nine` will match `nine` in `ninety`, so you should either put the longer values first, or use word boundaries `\b`
- Declare the pattern with a raw string literal to avoid issues like parsing `\b` as a backspace and not a word boundary
- To match digits, you may add a `|\d+` branch to your number matching group
- To match multiple non-overlapping occurrences of the substrings inside the input string, you need to use `re.findall` (or `re.finditer`), not `re.search`.

Here is my suggestion:

```
import re
text = 'one two three 10 number eleven eighteen ninety  \n '
numbers = r"""(?x)          # Turn on free spacing mode
            (
              ^a(?=\s)|     # Here we match a at the start of string before  whitespace
              \d+|          # HERE we match one or more digits
              \b            # Initial word boundary 
              (?:
                  one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten| 
                  eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen| 
                  eighteen|nineteen|twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty| 
                  ninety|hundred|thousand
              )             # A list of alternatives
              \b            # Trailing word boundary
)"""

print(re.findall(numbers, text))
```

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5l6rkc)

And here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mQ8aF2/2).

Answer (score 1):

Well the re.findall and the add of [0-9]+ work well for your list. Unfortunately if you try to match something like seventythree you will get --> seven and three, thus you need something better than this below :-)

```
numbers = "(^a(?=\s)|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten| \
          eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen| \
          eighteen|nineteen|twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty| \
          ninety|hundred|thousand|[0-9]+)"

x = re.findall(numbers, text)
```

Comment: Not only `seventythree`, this one won't match `eighteen`, `eleven`, `ninety`. And when it finds `sixteen`, it will only fetch `six`. See https://ideone.com/jBOsxt

Comment: Correct...this I was trying to point out :-) Yours looks better, but it want match seventythree. Isn't it?   Anyway one point plus for you...since it is really a useful piece of code!! :-)

Comment: If OP asks about matching `seventy-three`, I will see to it. Right now, there are enough issues to worry about :)

Comment: seventythree is not matched. I have added to your code a + --> this will help in matching multiple words (of course also in that case the match is still not perfect)

Comment: I do not think there is any need using a `+` there. Correct compoud numeral spelling is with a hyphen. Also, I doubt `nineteenthirty` match is expected.

Comment: Point is the matching of a false like --> seventythreenine correct you are right

Comment: Moreover the English dictionary reports the number with hyphen!! Another +1 :-)